# how to call this add function

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am using andSubject function to set the subject in the parent component but it's not working can someone help me how can I call addSubject when I press the RoundedButton?

```
...
const [tempItem, setTempItem] = useState(null);
.....
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            onSubmitEditing={({ nativeEvent }) => {
              setTempItem(nativeEvent.text);
              // addSubject(nativeEvent.text);
            }}
          />
          <RoundedButton
            title="+"
            size={50}
            onPress={() => addSubject(tempItem)}
          />
        </View>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this :

```
const [tempItem, setTempItem] = React.useState("");
const [addSubject , setAddSubject] = React.useState("");
        

...
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <Text>this text bellow will show after pressing on the button :</Text>
          <Text>{addSubject}</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                onChangeText={setTempItem}
              />
              <Button
                title="+"
                size={50}
                onPress={() => setAddSubject(tempItem)}
              />
            </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
```

...

[demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@shahem/32eb84)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the function to children by props.

parent.js

```
  function setAddSubject(item){
    console.log(item)
}

    <YourForm call={(item)=>setAddSubject(item) }  />
```

YourForm.js

```
    export default =(props)=>{
       const [tempItem, setTempItem] = useState(null);
    return (
           <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            onSubmitEditing={({ nativeEvent }) => {
              setTempItem(nativeEvent.text);
              // addSubject(nativeEvent.text);
            }}
          />
          <RoundedButton
            title="+"
            size={50}
            onPress={() => props.call(tempItem)}
          />
        </View>
          );
     }
```

Comment: its not working